# Use ForEach on an object retrieved from jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am passing a collection of values through ajax, then i can not able to retrieve these values from webmethod by foreach procedure.
my collection variable is  var Leave = { "Date": [], "Half": [] };
Passing Leave to webmethod but it is not possible to retrieve values
.pls help me.
my code is

```
empid = document.getElementById("hdnemployee").value;
if (empid != "") {
var Leave = { "Date": [], "Half": [] };
$('.leave_item').each(function () {
var cur = $(this);
var thisdate = cur.find('.txtdate').val();
Leave.Date.push(thisdate);                   
if (cur.find('.ckbhalfday').is(':checked'))                  
   Leave.Half.push(1);
else
   Leave.Half.push(0);                 
});
var arr = new Array();
console.log(Leave);         
arr[0] = document.getElementById('drpLeavetype').value;
//arr[1] = document.getElementById('TxtDatefrom').value;
//arr[2] = document.getElementById('TxtDateTo').value;
arr[3] = document.getElementById('Txtnumdays').value;
arr[4] = document.getElementById('txtDiscription').value;
if (arr[4] != "")
{
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         url: "Applyleave.aspx/saveleaveApply",
         data: JSON.stringify({ empid: empid,Leave:Leave, arr: arr }),
         success: function (msg) {
                            // document.getElementById("tblleaveapply").innerHTML = "";
                            $('#tblleaveapply').empty();
                            alert(msg.d);
                            resettxtfields();
                            BindLADetails();
                        },
                        error: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Give Reason");
                }

            }
            else {
                alert("Select employee");
            }
```

WebMethod:-

```
  [WebMethod]
   public static string saveleaveApply(string empid, object Leave, params string[] arr)
   {
      foreach( var c in Leave)
      {

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) statement on an object unless it implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` interface. What you need to do is define a `Type` in your code behind which will map to the JSON object something like this:-

```
public class Leave
{
    public string[] Date { get; set; }
    public string[] Half { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can modify your WebMethod as follows and iterate over the items:-

```
[WebMethod]
public static string saveleaveApply(string empid, Leave Leave, params string[] arr)
{
   foreach( var c in Leave.Date)
   {

   }

   foreach( var c in Leave.Half)
   {

   }
}
```

**Update:**
Although, I personally won't use this type, instead I will use:-

```
public class Leave
{
     public string Date { get; set; }
     public string Half { get; set; }
}
```

You need to fill this type in JS like this:-

```
var leave = new Array();
$('.leave_item').each(function() {
var cur = $(this);
var thisdate = cur.find('.txtdate').val();
var thishalf;
if (cur.find('.ckbhalfday').is(':checked'))                  
   thishalf = 1;
else
   thishalf = 0;   
 leave.push({ "Date": thisdate, "Half": thishalf });              
});
```

And Finally the WebMethod will look like this:-

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string saveleaveApply(string empid, Leave[] Leave, params string[] arr)
 {
     foreach( var c in Leave)
     {

     }
 }
```

Comment: Sir, when i set Leave[] as parameter type this is not accessible for my ajax method

Comment: @SalamIndianoor - What do you mean by not accessible..? Are you getting the values at server side? Which approach you followed first or second?

Comment: not accessible means this  ajax not found the specified webmethod. So values are not getting at server side

Comment: @SalamIndianoor - Please confirm if you are passing the data as `Leave:leave,`, here `leave` is the new array I have defined in my second approach, you need to remove your old code.

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({ empid: empid, Leave: leave, arr: arr }),
Is the values is passing as stringfy..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87368/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-salam-indianoor).

Comment: @SalamIndianoor - Yes but make sure `leave` is generated by the code I wrote for JS and not your code. You can join chat room and we can discuss properly.

Comment: thank you sir..this code is working fine with the class second updated Leave class